# Compound foreign key constraint with a String literal

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a compound primary key:

```
Table "account.enum"
Column   |          Type          | Modifiers
-----------+------------------------+-----------
classname | character varying(256) | not null
name      | character varying(64)  | not null
active    | boolean                | not null
Indexes: "enum_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (classname, name)
```

Values:

```
classname   |  name  | active
--------------+--------+--------
CURRENCY     | EUR    | t
CURRENCY     | USD    | t
MUTATIONTYPE | CREDIT | t
MUTATIONTYPE | DEBET  | t
```

Another table account uses this table:

```
Table "account.mutation"
Column      |          Type          |                       Modifiers
-----------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
id              | bigint                 | not null default nextval('mutation_id_seq'::regclass)
accountnumber   | character varying(9)   | not null
interestdate    | date                   | not null
balancebefore   | numeric(10,2)          | not null
balanceafter    | numeric(10,2)          | not null
transactiondate | date                   | not null
amount          | numeric(10,2)          | not null
description     | character varying(512) | not null
ordernumber     | smallint               | default (-1)
mutationtype    | character varying(64)  |
currency        | character varying(64)  |
```

I want to add foreign key constraints (for mutationtype and currency):

```
alter table mutation add constraint FK_mutationtype foreign key('MUTATIONTYPE', mutationtype) references enum(classname, name);
alter table mutation add constraint FK_currency     foreign key('CURRENCY', currency)         references enum(classname, name);
```

However the string literals are not accepted. 
What am I doing wrong? Is what I want possible in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this because foreign keys can only be defined on columns, not on expressions like the literal `'MUTATIONTYPE'`.

You could introduce a column like `mutation_class` in `mutation` that is always set to `'MUTATIONTYPE'`, but that sounds wasteful, redundant and silly.

I think that you should solve the problem by having different lookup tables for the different enumerations, then the difficulty would just vanish, and the whole design looks more reasonable from a relational perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

This means that I should create a new table for every enum I introduce.
Since all these tables are alike I'm looking for a single table solution.

Comment: What is the advantage of having a single table?

Comment: The enum table is automatically filled by Java if there are new enums or enum constants created in the Java code. I do not want to create (flyway) SQL script s every time a create or modify the Java enum classes.

Comment: You cannot write the Java code so that it uses different tables?

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.